# How can I Hide fields in browser inspector

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am new in Java and JQuery. I am using hidden field to hide my value but using Browser Inspector others can find my data. how can I hide values in Browser.

```
out.println("<form method='post' action='test.jsp'>");
out.println("<input type=hidden name=test1 value=" + test1 + " />");
out.println("<input type=hidden name=test2 value=" + test2 + " />");
out.println("<input type=hidden name=test3 value=" + test3 + " />");
out.println("<input type=hidden name=test4 value=" + test4 + " />");
out.println("<input type=submit value=Launch />");
out.println("</form>");
```

Comment: no you cant hide the code.

Comment: its that no possible?

Comment: basically you cannot, but you can have some level of privacy using [shadow-dom](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-shadow-dom--net-34966)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html renders the data on users browser, html standards offers you to hide data by only using hidden form fields, the initial purpose of hidden form field to allow session tracking.

with hidden form field user can view the content when he views the source,
if you want to hide data i suggest to use some kind of encryption.